# Gridview Binding DropDownList from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I need to bind grid view with check box column, droupdown column and text box. it is like default mode is edit. please help me to bind combo box items from code behind. Combo box values need to get from web service. all the grid data binding from code behind. user can change the data on grid.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked= "<%# Bind('select') %>" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roles">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Roles") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('Name') %>"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("select", typeof(bool));
    table.Columns.Add("Roles", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(true, "Admin", "name1" );
    table.Rows.Add(true, "Admin", "name2");
    table.Rows.Add(true, "user", "name3");
    table.Rows.Add(false, "user", "name4");
    table.Rows.Add(false, "Admin", "name5");
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
OnDataBound="DropDownList_OnDataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and

```
protected void DropDownList_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
   DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
   if(ddl != null)
   {
        // call web service and 
        // populate ddl.Items
   }
}
```